# Type of screw / fastener should one use to attach veneer covered particle board bookcases together?

Tags: furniture, cabinets, plywood

I have 8 [Ikea Billy bookcases](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/30279784/) and I would like to attach them together to make the seam betwen them as narrow as possible.

What sort of screw or fastener is appropriate for particle board?

Comment: It would be a bit more tricky (and possibly be a good question for [woodworking.se]), but you might be able to remove one side of every book case so that two neighbouring ones would share it. That'd certainly reduce the seam to a minimum. You could use the spare sides to create more shelves if necessary.

Comment: If you tried removing sides you might find that there wouldn't be a way to connect the fixed shelves and/or top and bottom pieces. Better to use the method below I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not a big fan of screw threads in particle board.

I would use [connecting bolts](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-4-in-x-1-3-16-in-Narrow-Black-Connecting-Bolt-2-Pack-818018/204675185) and [caps](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-4-in-20-x-12-mm-Connecting-Cap-Nut-in-Black-4-Pack-818098/204604824), which are often included in DIY furniture.

[image: connecting bolt][image: connecting cap]

They come in a wide variety of lengths and finishes. Pick the size and style that fit.

```
 Images and links are illustrative only, not an endorsment of goods or sources.
```

Comment: Alternate search term: "sex bolts"

Comment: ... or "sleeve bolts".

Answer (score 0):

I would talk to someone at Ikea about this. If you look on their site at Billy bookshelves, when they sell a wider version it is two bookshelves side by side and they do not share a single side piece. It appears to be two separate ones that they have tied together. So they must have a system for doing this and you can get the hardware from them.